# Sharepoint - Customizing Reports

Tags: reporting-services, reports

I've recently been given the task of customizing our reports on sharepoint.  Being brand new to sharepoint, I'm kinda walking through the dark.

I was wondering, is there a way to take the reports list (for example):

[image]

and the pages that are opened :

[image]

And combine them to one page.  Kind of like this very rough illustration:

[image]

Basically I need to config reports (manage subscriptions, parameters, etc..) all from one user friendly screen.  Eliminating all the tiered clicking and stuff.

I am not finding a lot of sources on this type of thing... just on customizing the individual reports.

Currently not worried about a report preview functionality, but if possible would be nice also.

Thank you,

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no well documented or proven solution for your question. But still reports published to SharePoint can be modified for parameters, data sources and so on from the edit properties of the each individual report.

I would also suggest to look for performance point services where you can embed reports with in the dashboard pages and configure the filters and parameters in a better way.